# Intuition About the Impossibility of Acceleration to C in Relativity. Is my Intuition Getting in the Way

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, time-dilation, intuition

Bob is riding a bicycle on a highway into space. His sister Alice watches him leave, and each rotation of the pedals brings Bob an absolute 1% closer to the speed of light relative to Alice. Bob also has infinite energy. Bob would never reach the speed of light relative to Alice. Each rotation of the pedal takes place over greater and greater lengths of time and space. The last full rotation of the pedals will never finish. Bob gets an allowance of time from the universe based off of his velocity relative to Alice. His  passage through time relative to Alice gets asymptomatically small as he approaches the speed of light so the work he does to reach the speed of light would have to take place over an infinite time relative to Alice and an infinite distance.
^^That is my intuition^^

I am only a layman and not a physicist or mathematician with experience with Relativity. I have been searching the web for a few days for an answer, but haven't seen any simple answers that line up with my intuition of the impossibility of acceleration to the speed of light.

My issue is with the need for infinite energy being the barrier to accelerating to the speed of light for anything with mass. It makes sense on paper, but my intuition tells me to view the limiting factor as time. And this results in the need for infinite energy.

Is this a difference without a consequence? Or is it crucial to conceptualize the limit the other way around?

I'm just trying to get reasonable a layman's intuition  for that impossibility.

Answer (score 1):

Time and energy are related at a very deep level (conservation of energy, for example, is related to the the laws of physics being the same at different times). So in some sense you could either look at the requirement for accelerating to $c$ as being an infinite amount of time or an infinite amount of energy; either way it's impossible in our universe.

Another way to conceptualize it is that in relativity the constant $c$ basically fills the roll of "infinitely fast" in Newtonian mechanics -- that is, the theory of relativity reduces to Newtonian mechanics in the limit as $c \rightarrow \infty$. This provides another reason that FTL travel is problematic: going faster than light is like going "faster than infinitely fast", i.e. it means traveling backwards in time. See for example the paradoxes that could be created by a [tachyonic antitelephone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tachyonic_antitelephone)